# Can python/matplotlib's confourf be made to plot a limited region of data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

Am trying to make a contour plot with matplotlib's contourf.  Is there a way to zoom in on a particular region of my data and leave the rest unplotted?  For instance, maybe my horizontal extent goes from -1 to 101, but I just want to plot the data that's in between 0 and 100 inclusive, *and* I want the boundary of the plot to be drawn at 0 on the left and 100 on the right.  I thought the "extent" keyword would do the job, but it is inactive when X and Y data are given.  I know that I can mask the extraneous data in various ways, but that leaves the boundaries of the plot drawn beyond my region of interest, which is not what I want.  I guess I could also filter or interpolate my data to my region of interest and then give that filtered data to contourf, but if I can just make contourf focus on a particular region, it would be alot easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `plt.xlim`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-1,101,100)
y = np.linspace(-1,101,100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x*x+y*y
plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 50)
plt.contourf(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Above, `plt.xlim(0, 50)` was used instead of `plt.xlim(0,100)` just to emphasize the change. Without `plt.xlim(0, 50)` the plot looks like this:

[image]